# Stanford NLP annotation ranking or score

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP pipeline and am getting `TreeAnnotation` and `BasicDependenciesAnnotation` from `SentencesAnnotation`.
I am looking for a way to tell how certain is the parser about POS tags and dependency structure.

I remember that earlier while I was tinkering with Stanford NLP libraries I saw somewhere mutiple trees with different ranking returned for the same sentence. 
I cannot find any information on how to get this from the parser or pipeline.

`DependencyScoring` class seems to be operating on `TypedDependency`, not something pipeline produces as part of annotation process, as far as I can tell.

**EDIT:** The code details:

```
Annotation document = new Annotation("This is my sentence");
pipeline.annotate(document); 
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
...
Tree tree = sentence1.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence1.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: How are you producing dependency parses? Are you getting them from the `parse` annotator? If this is the case, the dependencies are actually produced by deterministic conversions — your only measure of probability would come from the PCFG parses from which conversion begins. I can provide more detail if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Basically I do "Annotation document = new Annotation("This is my sentence"); pipeline.annotate(document); List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);" and then get TreeAnnotation and Dependency Graph.
Yes, please do elaborate on the PCFG approach.

Comment: @JonGauthier Also, is it possible to see likelihood/probability of the word pairs in dependency relationships? E.g. how probable is it to encounter "MD"->"JJ" or "will"->"able" relationship?
If you want I can post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default CoreNLP pipeline (i.e., with the `parse` annotator and not `depparse`), the dependency parses you are seeing are coming from a deterministic conversion of a constituency parse of the sentence. The best "score" you can get here would be to **look at the candidate constituency parses** that eventually yield dependency parses (after conversion).

You'll need to break out of the CoreNLP pipeline to do this specific work, however. If you have a `LexicalizedParser` instance, you can get the *k* best parses (with attached scores) like so:

```
List<CoreLabel> mySentence = ...

LexicalizedParser parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
ParserQuery pq = parser.parserQuery();
if (pq.parse(mySentence)) {
  // Get best parse and associated score
  Tree parse = pq.getBestPCFGParse();
  double score = pq.getPCFGScore();

  // Print parse
  parse.pennPrint();

  // ----
  // Get collection of best parses
  List<ScoredObject<Tree>> bestParses = pq.getBestPCFGParses();

  // ----
  // Convert a constituency parse to dependency representation
  GrammaticalStructure gs = parser.treebankLanguagePack()
      .grammaticalStructureFactory().newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
  List<TypedDependency> dependencies = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
  System.out.println(dependencies);
}
```

Relevant Javadoc:

- [`ParserQuery`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/common/ParserQuery.html)
- [`GrammaticalStructure`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalStructure.html)
- [`ScoredObject`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/ScoredObject.html)

(NB: untested code, but this should work..)